# first value in dropdown column selected on editing kendo grid

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, kendo-grid, kendo-dropdown

I am working with kendo grid that contains dropdown column in it. when I edit record then first record in dropdown list is selected except of which column value given into it as `dataItem.SurahId` in below code. I am using inline dropdown defined in html view except of in javascript controller.

```
{ field: "SurahId", title:"Surah", template: "#= getSurahName(SurahId)#", editor : "<input kendo-drop-down-list k-data-text-field=\"&#39;ArabicName&#39;\" k-data-value-field=\"&#39;Id&#39;\" k-data-source=\"surahDS\"  ng-model=\"dataItem.SurahId\" />" },
```

The whole code for grid is given below.

```
<div class="k-content" style="width: 100%">
                <div kendo-grid="grid"
                     k-sortable="true"
                     k-pageable="true"
                     k-filterable="true"
                     k-editable="'inline'"
                     k-selectable="true"                                                                                                
                     k-toolbar='[ { template: toolbarTemplate } ]'
                     k-columns='[
                        { field: "No", title:"No." },
                        { field: "SurahId", title:"Surah", template: "#= getSurahName(SurahId)#", editor : "<input kendo-drop-down-list k-data-text-field=\"&#39;ArabicName&#39;\" k-data-value-field=\"&#39;Id&#39;\" k-data-source=\"surahDS\"  ng-model=\"dataItem.SurahId\" />" },
                        { field: "Address", title: "Address" },                        
                        { field: "LetterCount", title: "Letters"},
                        { field: "HasSajadah", title: "Has Sajadah",  template: "#= HasSajadah ? \"Yes\" : \"No\" #" }]'
                     k-data-source="dataSource"
                     k-on-data-bound="onDataBound(kendoEvent)"
                     k-on-change="onChange(kendoEvent)">
                </div>
                <style scoped>
                    .toolbar { padding: 15px; float: right; }
                </style>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I diagnosed actual problem. give name attribute to the editor input because the Grid will know which property of the model to select/update. name should be same as field name as shown below. record will also not be updated without name defined in input control.

```
editor : "<input kendo-drop-down-list name=\"SurahId\"
```